# Schedule Query Partition Table Hourly

Tags: google-bigquery

I have schedule query which runs hourly I want to partition the table hourly so in the destinaltion I have provided this `mytable_{run_time|"%Y%m%d%H"}`, but this is creating a new table for every run  in my BigQuery datasets , when I change the destination to `mytable_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}`, it's partition the data correctly based on date

How to enable hourly partition in big query ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is aligned to table sharding, which you can do but it is not as performant and involves more management.  In theory it acts similarly to a partition but is not the same. What you are likely seeing when you use the format `mytable_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}` is that you're inserting multiple hours into the same day, and depending on what your table definition is may be partitioned within a single day.

You will want to define the partition in the creation of the table see below:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#create_a_time-unit_column-partitioned_table

Comment: so I need to do the following - In the Partition and cluster settings section, for Partitioning, click Partition by ingestion time  and select `hourly` and in schedule query I just need to mentioned the name ?

Comment: I tried that it's not happening as expected

Comment: So i've been running some tests with this and it seems, from what I can tell the functionality may be off in scheduled queries to insert into an hourly partition directly.  Per the documentation to insert into an ingestion-time partition table, having the scheduled query create the table, needs to utilize the following syntax of mytable$YYYYMMDD, this however does not seem to extend to an hourly partition.

Comment: as I get the error message ```Job scheduled_query_61b2ac02-0000-2234-9e67-94eb2c03504e (table so_pt_test$2021081115) failed with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid date partitioned partition key: 2021081115; JobID: 246393112696:scheduled_query_61b2ac02-0000-2234-9e67-94eb2c03504e``` 
even though YYYYMMDDHH is a valid partition definition.

Comment: An Alternative approach that I have validated would be to create the table ahead of time.  In the scheduled query definition use the vanilla table name, ie `mytable` and leave the partition column empty.